# AWS stop alarm not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I cannot get alarms to work reliably for an AWS ec2 instance. I have a g2.xlarge image running and want it to stop when it is not in use, i.e. when average usage falls below 2%.

When I try 1 or 2 periods of 1 hour below 2% it usually works but then when I start it up again it immediately stops itself as it is in an alarm condition. I have tried 12 periods of 5 minutes which allows it to start ok but now it doesn't stop at all despite being in an alarm condition for several hours.

I have tried various options and can't nail down what makes it work and what doesn't. It feels as if sometimes things work and sometimes they don't. Is it buggy or am I missing something?

Here is a screenshot of my setup which has failed to trigger a shutdown...
[image]

Comment: 12 Consecutive period of 5 Min is it has to rain below 2 Percent for 1 Hour straight? Correct

Comment: Yes, each 5 minute period must average below 2 percent, which adds up to an hour. The utilisation graph in the screenshot is now up to 24 consecutive periods below 2 percent and it still hasn't been stopped. It does show an alarm condition.